# iOS : How to check if user canceled Google+ login

Tags: ios, ios7, google-plus, google-signin

I use Google+ SDK to login to app using Google+. If user is redirected to a login page and taps `cancel` button then below error is thrown.

```
Error Domain=com.google.GooglePlusPlatform Code=-1 "Unknown error" UserInfo=0xd5e37b0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown error},
```

`Code` they set in `NSError` cannot be used to distinguish between events that user canceled login or any other error. Because the same `Code` is used for other error. Below is an example.

```
Error Domain=com.google.GooglePlusPlatform Code=-1 "Mismatched authentication" UserInfo=0xd5968e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Mismatched authentication},
```

And checking error message is not a reliable way.

Then how to check for this?

Answer (score -3):

> Make sure you signout in case of error.

```
 -(void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                      error: (NSError *) error {

         if (error) {

        // use nslog to get the exact error

       // make sure you do this in case of error, sign out the user.

         [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];

       } else {
        GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
        NSLog(@"User ID:%@", signIn.userID);
        NSLog(@"User Email:%@", signIn.userEmail);

    }

}
```